# What does this Objective-C statement mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can usually decipher unfamiliar code, given a few minutes, but what is this:

```
    NSNumber *one = [NSNumber numberWithInt:rand()%60+20];
```

It's from XYPieChart.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a random number, modulo 60, plus 20, put into an NSNumber.  (In other words, a number between 20 and 79.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**rand()** Returns a pseudo-random integral number in the range between 0 and RAND_MAX. see [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/)

**%** is modulo operator and finds the remainder of division of one number by another. See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

**rand() % 60** = Number in range 0 to 59

**rand()%60+20** = Number in range 20 to 79

[**NSNumber**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a subclass of NSValue that offers a value as any C scalar (numeric) type.

```
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithInt:(int)value
```

Above class method of NSNumber creates and returns an NSNumber object containing a given value, treating it as a signed int.

```
NSNumber *one = [NSNumber numberWithInt:rand()%60+20];
```

So the above statement is initialising "one" with NSNumber initialised with random integer between 20 to 79.

Comment: I appreciate it. Actually looks like a useful thing, once I stretched my head around it. Thanks!

Comment: @TimJones glad that the answer helped.